# How to save and restore Tensorflow model made with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am currently working on a project where I build a Network in Keras like so:

```
 inputstuff = Input(shape=(32,), name='main_input')
 encoded = Dense(16, activation='relu',init='he_normal',  activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01))(inputstuff)
 [other layers...]
 decoded = Dense(32, activation='relu',init='he_normal', name='main_output')(decoded)
 autoencoder = Model(input=inputstuff, output=decoded)
```

Next to save this file as a tensorflow model, I do the following:

```
 sessK=K.get_session() 
 saver = tf.train.Saver()
 model_path = "/tmp/KerasGlobalAEModel.ckpt"
 save_path = saver.save(sessK, model_path)
```

Next I want to load the file from another program:

```
 model_path = "/tmp/KerasGlobalAEModel.ckpt"
 tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(model_path)
 with tf.Session() as sess:
 # Initialize variables
     init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
     sess.run(init)

     saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/tmp/KerasGlobalAEModel.ckpt.meta')

    # Restore model weights from previously saved model
     saver.restore(sess, model_path)



     test = [some data]
     graph = tf.get_default_graph()

     MyAnswers = sess.run(Y*, feed_dict={X*: test})
```

If this was the same file I would be able to use:

```
 X* = model.input
 Y* = model.output
```

However, this and all other things I have tried failed.

Here is a list of what DOES NOT work.

- Y = graph.get_tensor_by_name("main_output")
- Y = model.output
- Y = autoencoder.output

I realize I am a noobie at this, and this might be a dumb question but I would appreciate any guidance.

Thank you,

Comment: Why did it fail? Please be very specific about what happened and what you expected to happen.

Comment: Instead of using tf saver, why don't you just use `model.save()` and `keras.models.load_model()` directly like [this](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)?

Comment: E_net4: The error given for the first 2 methods was that I was not passing a proper tensor.

Comment: scarecrow: That is definitely a possibility. it just seems a bit cumbersome, but you are absolutely right, if there is no way to do otherwise I will have to load the Keras model and then grab the TF graph